# Java : Subclass inheritance without all of the Superclass instance variables/methods

Tags: java

A theoretical question :
Is it possible to create a subclass B from a superclass A inheriting all of the A's instance variables/methods except a specific instance variable/method from superclass A ?

Comment: Ummm...no. No, it is not.

Comment: If you had the need, it would be a mis-use of inheritance. It would break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: To what end? You can override what you don't like.

Comment: You "accepted" the wrong answer. -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation suggests that A contains too much to be a good base class.

Create a class C that contains those portions of A's implementation that you expect to be generally useful to inherit. Make both A and B extend C, specializing it to their requirements. C can be abstract.

Comment: This is the best and correct answer. Fix the design rather than try to shoehorn a poor solution. 1+

Comment: +1. Or don't depend too much on subclasses for code reuse and employ composition and delegation instead.

Answer (score 4):

No. If B inherits from A, it inherits everything from A. (Though it can *override* the method implementations provided by A.)

However, you *can* wrap an A inside a B, using composition rather than inheritance. In B, expose only the specific instance method you want to expose.

Answer (score -1):

Just to clear, the B would inherit the methods of A, not include the A's **instance** variables.

if you hope that the B don't inherit the one specific method or variable of A, you could declare the **final** key words.

Comment: `"if you hope that the B don't inherit the one specific method or variable of A, you could declare the final key words."` -- This is incorrect as final only prevents the method from being overridden, not from being inherited. Please see [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html)

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to inherit, make them private.

Comment: Well, even you make it private, it is still "inherited".  It is just the child cannot access that.  However it is still "part of" the child.